# Mongodb local session cache refresh is not working

Tags: mongodb

We have this mongo cluster running. the number of logical sessions never goes down and we end up hitting 1 million(`maxSessions: 1000000`) limit. I printed `db.serverStatus().logicalSessionRecordCache` and it gives me this me this output

```
{                                                                        
  activeSessionsCount: 911870,                                           
  sessionsCollectionJobCount: 234,                                       
  lastSessionsCollectionJobDurationMillis: 0,                            
  lastSessionsCollectionJobTimestamp: ISODate("2022-02-26T23:20:18.584Z")
  lastSessionsCollectionJobEntriesRefreshed: 986207,                     
  lastSessionsCollectionJobEntriesEnded: 13794,                          
  lastSessionsCollectionJobCursorsClosed: 0,                             
  transactionReaperJobCount: 1448,                                       
  lastTransactionReaperJobDurationMillis: 0,                             
  lastTransactionReaperJobTimestamp: ISODate("2022-03-01T00:27:35.342Z"),
  lastTransactionReaperJobEntriesCleanedUp: 0,                           
  sessionCatalogSize: 0                                                  
}
```

`lastSessionsCollectionJobTimestamp` from the docs says 'The time at which the last refresh occurred'. And that is more than 2 days ago, which should every 5 minutes from the `logicalSessionRefreshMillis: 300000` parameter.
I am posting here to find how can I get more information on this issue that why local refresh is not happening. Also, our `db('config').getCollection('system.sessions')` is also empty.

Comment: In order to help with finding a solution, here are my observations: It started with an older installation of 3.6, which had been running fine for two or three years, but suddenly having this too-many-logical-sessions problem, then stops running more queries. Updating to 4.0 and setting these parameters weren't any help: `--setParameter logicalSessionRefreshMillis=10000 --setParameter localLogicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=5`